# How do I create a table in kdb using different data of different lengths?

Tags: kdb

```
count times:102
count area:3
count no.of_people:2

t:ungroup([]time:times;area:(count [times])#enlist area;no.of_people:count[times]#enlist no.of_people )
```

Currently getting a length error.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The `ungroup` is failing with `'length` because the number of entries per column is not uniform, IE `area` has 3 entries and `no.of_people` has 2.

```
q)times:102?.z.t
q)area:`area1`area2`area3
q)no.of_people:10 20
q)([]time:times;area:(count [times])#enlist area;no.of_people:count[times]#enlist no.of_people)
time         area              no.of_people
-------------------------------------------
19:01:02.988 area1 area2 area3 10 20
16:10:13.387 area1 area2 area3 10 20
00:42:09.536 area1 area2 area3 10 20
15:13:03.964 area1 area2 area3 10 20
08:35:51.109 area1 area2 area3 10 20
..
```

It's not clear from your description what your desired output is, but if you remove the `enlist` from the column declaration a table is returned.

```
/ This returns 102 lists of 10 20
q)count[times]#enlist no.of_people
10 20
10 20
10 20
10 20
10 20
..
/ This returns one 102 item list of 10 20 repeated
q)count[times]#no.of_people
10 20 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 20 10 20..
q)([]time:times;area:(count [times])#area;no.of_people:count[times]#no.of_people )
time         area  no.of_people
-------------------------------
19:01:02.988 area1 10
16:10:13.387 area2 20
00:42:09.536 area3 10
15:13:03.964 area1 20
08:35:51.109 area2 10
..
```

Otherwise, to have your initial `ungroup` work you will need to ensure columns have the same number of entries per row (columns with one entry per row are “vector expanded”).

```
q)([]time:times;area:(count [times])#enlist area;no.of_people:(count [times])#enlist count[area]#no.of_people)
time         area              no.of_people
-------------------------------------------
19:01:02.988 area1 area2 area3 10 20 10
16:10:13.387 area1 area2 area3 10 20 10
00:42:09.536 area1 area2 area3 10 20 10
15:13:03.964 area1 area2 area3 10 20 10
08:35:51.109 area1 area2 area3 10 20 10
..
q)ungroup([]time:times;area:(count [times])#enlist area;no.of_people:(count [times])#enlist count[area]#no.of_people)
time         area  no.of_people
-------------------------------
19:01:02.988 area1 10
19:01:02.988 area2 20
19:01:02.988 area3 10
16:10:13.387 area1 10
16:10:13.387 area2 20
..
```